# Forge 1.12.2 / Cannot synchronise client and server

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Possible the problem is not even in this, however, I don't know why my code is still not working correctly.

**Task**: Write a Minecraft 1.12.2 mod that performs a right-click (RMB) on behalf of the player when the number 6 is present in the title bar on the screen.

**Code**:

Imports:

```
package com.example.examplemod;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiIngame;
import net.minecraft.client.settings.KeyBinding;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumHand;
import net.minecraft.util.text.TextComponentString;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.registry.ClientRegistry;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.ObfuscationReflectionHelper;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.EventPriority;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.InputEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
```

Declaration of all fields, etc.:

```
@Mod(modid = ExampleMod.MODID, name = ExampleMod.NAME, version = ExampleMod.VERSION)
public class ExampleMod {
    public static final String MODID = "examplemod";
    public static final String NAME = "Example Mod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";
    public static KeyBinding[] keyBindings = { new KeyBinding("key.toggleMod.desc", Keyboard.KEY_RMENU, "key.categories.mod") };
    private boolean modEnabled = false;
    private Field displayedTitleField;
    private final Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
```

Initialization during client startup. Added the search for `displayedTitleField` here right away because they say that `ObfuscationReflectionHelper` is quite slow, so it's better to use it once:

```
    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
        ClientRegistry.registerKeyBinding(keyBindings[0]);
        displayedTitleField = ObfuscationReflectionHelper.findField(GuiIngame.class, "field_175201_x");
        displayedTitleField.setAccessible(true);
    }
```

Code for simulating enabling/disabling the mod:

```
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onKeyInput(InputEvent.KeyInputEvent event) {
        if (keyBindings[0].isPressed()) {
            modEnabled = !modEnabled;
            EntityPlayer player = Minecraft.getMinecraft().player;
            player.sendMessage(new TextComponentString(modEnabled ? "Mod enabled!" : "Mod disabled!"));
        }
    }
```

Problematic part. The `onTick` method is called every tick. If the current value of `currentTitle` contains "a6" (a - color code before the number 6 to avoid triggering on other sixes), then a right-click is performed, and the mod is "disabled". `assert currentTitle != null;` - a placeholder to prevent `NullPointerException`, I will remove it later (however, if you remove it, I won't object :) ). `currentTitle` does contain the current value in the title bar on the screen, I made sure of it using `mc.player.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("Current displayedTitle: " + currentTitle));`, which is also a temporary placeholder.

```
    @SubscribeEvent(priority = EventPriority.NORMAL, receiveCanceled = true)
    public void onTick(TickEvent.ClientTickEvent event) {
        if (event.phase == TickEvent.Phase.START) {
            if (modEnabled) {
                String currentTitle = getCurrentTitle();
                assert currentTitle != null;
                mc.player.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("Current displayedTitle: " + currentTitle));
                if (currentTitle.contains("a6")) {
                    mc.playerController.processRightClick(mc.player, mc.world, EnumHand.MAIN_HAND);
                    modEnabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Method to get the text from the title bar:

```
    public String getCurrentTitle() {
        try {
            GuiIngame ingameGUI = mc.ingameGUI;
            if (ingameGUI != null) {
                String displayedTitle = (String) displayedTitleField.get(ingameGUI);
                return displayedTitle != null ? displayedTitle : "";
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

The problem is that in my case, random numbers from 1 to 6 appear on the screen every 4 ticks. And my mod either clicks RMB too early or, conversely, lags behind by several ticks. I don't know, but most of the time it clicks RMB at the wrong time when the number on the screen is no longer 6 but another number.

Here's the complete code for those who want to copy everything at once:

```
package com.example.examplemod;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiIngame;
import net.minecraft.client.settings.KeyBinding;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumHand;
import net.minecraft.util.text.TextComponentString;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.registry.ClientRegistry;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.ObfuscationReflectionHelper;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.EventPriority;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.InputEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

@Mod(modid = ExampleMod.MODID, name = ExampleMod.NAME, version = ExampleMod.VERSION)
public class ExampleMod {
    public static final String MODID = "examplemod";
    public static final String NAME = "Example Mod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";
    public static KeyBinding[] keyBindings = { new KeyBinding("key.toggleMod.desc", Keyboard.KEY_RMENU, "key.categories.mod") };
    private boolean modEnabled = false;
    private Field displayedTitleField;
    private final Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
        ClientRegistry.registerKeyBinding(keyBindings[0]);
        displayedTitleField = ObfuscationReflectionHelper.findField(GuiIngame.class, "field_175201_x");
        displayedTitleField.setAccessible(true);
    }
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onKeyInput(InputEvent.KeyInputEvent event) {
        if (keyBindings[0].isPressed()) {
            modEnabled = !modEnabled;
            EntityPlayer player = Minecraft.getMinecraft().player;
            player.sendMessage(new TextComponentString(modEnabled ? "Mod enabled!" : "Mod disabled!"));
        }
    }
    @SubscribeEvent(priority = EventPriority.NORMAL, receiveCanceled = true)
    public void onTick(TickEvent.ClientTickEvent event) {
        if (event.phase == TickEvent.Phase.START) {
            if (modEnabled) {
                String currentTitle = getCurrentTitle();
                assert currentTitle != null;
                mc.player.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("Current displayedTitle: " + currentTitle));
                if (currentTitle.contains("a6")) {
                    mc.playerController.processRightClick(mc.player, mc.world, EnumHand.MAIN_HAND);
                    modEnabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public String getCurrentTitle() {
        try {
            GuiIngame ingameGUI = mc.ingameGUI;
            if (ingameGUI != null) {
                String displayedTitle = (String) displayedTitleField.get(ingameGUI);
                return displayedTitle != null ? displayedTitle : "";
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

I tried using the `onRenderGameOverlay` method, but even though it has more iterations than 20 ticks per second, it still "clicks" RMB at the wrong time.